# Arduino mega2560 websocket не работает

Tags: websocket, arduino

Здравия всем!

Arduino mega2560 pro.
Ethernet shield mini w5100.

Web server работает нормально.

Однако, websocket сервер, когда уже должен создать клиента (на уровне tcp все норм и клиент посылает запрос на upgrade), полностью перезагружает плату...

Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: У меня была подобная ситуация, но с арудиной и esp8266. Помогли пляски с бубном и тасование версий библиотек.

Comment: Да я уж 2 дня перебираю....